# How to SELECT CASE LIKE in BigQuery

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery, case, sql-like

Can you assist in how to translate this pseudo code into BigQuery?

```
select case product_id when like 'a%' then -1 
       when product_id like 'b%' then -2 
       else product_id end as product_id
from `some.table.name`
```

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there. Basically, you need to use the long form of `case`, where conditions are repeated in each `when` branch; the short form that you are using is supported for equality conditions only.

Another problem is that all branches of a `case` expression must return the same datatype; it seems like `product_id` is a string, so you need to return strings rather than numbers, to be consistent with the `else` branch.

So:

```
select case 
    when product_id like 'a%' then '-1'
    when product_id like 'b%' then '-2' 
    else product_id 
end as product_id
from `some.table.name`
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option (BigQuery Standard SQL) to use "short" form of case as in below example

```
#standardSQL
select 
  case substr(product_id, 1, 1)
    when 'a' then '-1'
    when 'b' then '-2' 
    else product_id 
  end as product_id
from `some.table.name`
```